# Customize a WebPart without "target audiences"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hy,

I use SharePoint Foundation 2010 and I learned that the "target audiences" are disabled on the Foundation version.

I need to customize a WebPart on a wiki page when A user of a certain group is connected.

Have you an idea ?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: After research on the web, I have found this class "SPSecurityTrimmedControl" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx). Everyone has already used this class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. 
I insert JavaScript code in a WebPart in my wiki page from my SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively you can add a new web part page in your SharePoint site
>   and then add this Documents web part on the page. Once it is done,
>   Give access to only intended users for this page. Which means control
>   access at page level.

[source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/4293c963-a8fd-4325-8b70-813551492f62/hide-web-part-for-unauthorized-users-sp-2013-foundation)

Comment: Precisely I have a wiki page with 3 WebPart. I have 1 WebPart for 1 user group.